# Why are redundant columns being added when read and write a .csv file using pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
df = pd.read_csv("accounts.csv")
df.to_csv("accounts.csv")
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   Unnamed: 0   Email   Password
0           0  email1  password1
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1   Email   Password
0           0             0  email1  password1
   Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 0.1  Unnamed: 0.1.1   Email   Password
0           0             0               0  email1  password1
```

Can't add/ append rows properly this way.

Comment: Can yo provide more details about your csv. By default pandas add one default index for each row which is unnamed but not for all columns. default row index is 0 based

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({"Email": [], "Password": []})
df.to_csv("accounts.csv")

used this code to create accounts.csv

Comment: how can I add a row to the csv file? ,thats what i was trying to do when I encountered this extra index problem.

Answer (score 0):

in the t_csv command add: index=False

```
df.to_csv("accounts.csv", index=False)
```

And add the following command to the read_csv command: , index_col=0:

```
df = pd.read_csv("accounts.csv", index_col=0)
```

Comment: index_col = 0 is somehow switching the columns

Comment: pLS ,MARK MY ANSWER